# JS bookmark script

Tags: javascript

I have found a JS function that allows to add BOOKMARK link on a page. It works in IE, Firefox and Opera. I've tested in in Safari and Chrome and those two are not working. I'd like to add those as well.

Here's my [current function](http://jsfiddle.net/fA53E/6/).

Comment: You can go for an alternative, unobtrusive solution instead, and create an image with a link to your website, then ask your users to drag this image to their bookmarks bar :)

Comment: Is it for Safari? I can't really use images. The text is being translated based on region.

Comment: The image doesn't have to be text.  It can be your site's logo, or something.

Comment: Isnt a script allowing this actually a security issue? Shouldnt every browser stop you from doing this via script?

Answer (score 1):

@Pointy, script supports Opera by not working gracefully under it :-) There is/was *sidebar* "solution" similar to Mozilla's and it similarly sucks because `sidebar != bookmark` and noone wants sidebar pollution or bother with unchecking sidebar checkbox. @OP, put that script back where you found it and better focus on enduser-friendly text asking and guiding bookmarking process. SRSLY, adding a bookmark is **really** simple (2 keystrokes), this script makes it twice more complex.

Comment: +1. If it were really practical/feasible to provide cross-browser Add Bookmark links that hook into the real browser bookmarks and not some janky sidebar that nobody uses, there would be one _every single page on the entire Internet._ I recommend just being grateful that that's not the case and moving on with your day :^)

Comment: @RwL, agree, given social-engineering aspect of scripted initiation of bookmarking process (there are zillions of users who dismiss "add bookmark" dialog without actually reading it)